# iOS Thread Loop Logic

Tags: ios, json, multithreading

Im a little confused on the logic of creating a loop on a thread that is continuous . Just need a point in the Right Direction.
GCD or NSOpereation?

I have this JSON file that gets updated from a web job every 5 minutes.

Is there a way I can run a thread in the background that constantly checks the JSON for changes every N minutes or seconds ?

I', thinking i could use, just cant figure how I would implement

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using NSTimer with *repeats: true*:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(300, target: self, selector: Selector("checkForJSONChanges"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func checkForJSONChanges() {
    ...
}
```

Or if you're using Objective-C:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:300.0f target:self selector:@selector(checkForJSONChanges) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


- (void) checkForJSONChanges {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! thats perfect